# WCF: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string

Tags: sql-server, wcf

I just got this error and I thought I'd share it so that someone else doesn't spend an hour trying to figure out what's gone wrong.  I have SQL Server 2008 Express and a WCF service that was working fine.  All of a sudden it stopped working.  This was the error message

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken
>   string.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace
>   is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext() at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.GetObjectContext(Object
>   o) at System.Data.Services.Caching.MetadataCache`1.TryLookup(Type
>   serviceType, Object dataContextInstance) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&
>   metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&
>   queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object&
>   dataSourceInstance) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest()
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the SQL Server Windows service somehow was stopped.  Upon restarting it, everything worked fine again.